# Python - AttributeError: module 'cssutils' has no attribute 'getUrl'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extract URLs from CSS stylesheet using cssutils.getUrls('stylesheet.css')

However when I run the code I get an error complaining about 'getUrls' see below. I am running on python 3.6

> > > import cssutils
> > >       cssutils.getUrls('http://4nprofessionals.com/css/style.css')
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           cssutils.getUrls('http://4nprofessionals.com/css/style.css')
> > >       AttributeError: module 'cssutils' has no attribute 'getUrls'

Comment: can you please check your cssutils is properly installed?

Comment: it works fine for me!

Comment: cssutils  seems to be working I guess. See what I get when I type cssutils in the shell:>>> cssutils
<module 'cssutils' (namespace)>
>>>

Comment: I re-installed cssutils and now I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/image-read-write-logo-v2.2.py", line 5, in <module>
    import cssutils #css parser
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cssutils\__init__.py", line 321
    except xml.dom.HierarchyRequestErr, e:
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: try cmd>python>import cssutils and tell me the ouptut you see!

Comment: I typed import cssutils in Python shell and got this error:                                     >>> import cssutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    import cssutils
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cssutils\__init__.py", line 321
    except xml.dom.HierarchyRequestErr, e:
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: I reintstalled cssutils and got that error taken care of. However, the getUrls function does not seem to be getting those URLs. See code below:>>> import cssutils
>>> css = cssutils.getUrls('http://4nprofessionals.com/css/style.css')
>>> print (css)
<generator object getUrls at 0x000001647F6B4F10>
>>>

Comment: i think cssutils is not installed in your python libs at C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages‌.
Go to this location and check if cssutils folder exits!

Comment: I checked, it exists but the code is complaining about line 211 in _ini_.py  inside the cssutils folder:  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cssutils\__init__.py", line 211, in getUrls
    for importrule in (r for r in sheet if r.type == r.IMPORT_RULE):
  File "C:\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cssutils\__init__.py", line 211, in <genexpr>
    for importrule in (r for r in sheet if r.type == r.IMPORT_RULE):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'type'